# Assigning a subsearch result to a variable

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a Splunk dashboard that shows traffic across two sites. I need to get a) the number of users for each domain and b) the total users for use in the dashboard. At this time, I have the following Simple XML:

```
  <search id="app_logs">
    <query>
      index=my_logs
      | eval domain1Count = [
          search "Middleware" "www.example-domain-1.com"
          | stats distinct_count(UserId) as domain1Users
        ] 

      | eval domain2Count = [
          search "Middleware 2" "www.example-domain-2.com"
          | stats distinct_count(UserId) as domain2Users
        ] 
    
      | eval totalCount = domain1Count + domain2Count
      | table 
        domain1Count
        domain2Count
        totalCount
    </query>

    <done>
      <set token="domain1Count">$result.domain1Count$</set>
      <set token="domain2Count">$result.domain2Count$</set>
      <set token="totalCount">$result.totalCount$</set>
    </done>
  </search>
```

The query doesn't work as is. The `eval` statements generate errors. However, the queries on the right side of the `eval` statements work as expected. How do I assign a variable the single value of a subsearch so that I can use the values as tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do this as separate searches on the dashboard, unless there was an overwhelming need to have it all in one

Alternatively, you could `| append` each search, & `| stats values` at the ed like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp "middleware 1" "domain1.tld" userid=*
| stats dc(userid) as domain1users
| append
    [| search index=ndx sourcetype=srctp "middleware 2" "domain2.tld" userid=*
    | stats dc(userid) as domain2users ]
| stats values(*) as *
```

Then in your `<done>...</done>` clause, have multiple `<set token="...">$results.domain{N}users</set>` pairs

Answer (score 0):

A subsearch replaces itself with its results in the main search.  To see what the substitution is, run the subsearch with `| format` appended.  If the result makes sense in the context of the main search then you're OK; otherwise, adjust the subsearch to produce working results.  In this case, the subsearch will generate something like `domain2Users=3`, which results in `eval domain2Count = domain2Users=3`, which is invalid.

@warren's approach is much better.